# PPA for Spring Tool Suit

Tags: eclipse, spring, ide

I need to install STS in my linux machine.
In Spring site they are providing zip files for installation of STS.

But I am not getting any updates of STS with the system update
Is there any ppas available for STS. so that update will happen with the system update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no Linux platform packages for STS (as far as I know). It is designed to be executed as an app with user privileges, so there isn't really a lot of benefit in having a formal package for it. Just unzip the distro and run it.

Comment: Well actually there's a package for eclipse itself so ther's no reason to avoid the STS/GGTS one.